# How to deserialize multiple xsd versions into one class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-deserialization

My application reads in a certain type of XML files. I was provided with an XSD that I could deserialize using Visual Studio's `xsd` tool. Now, there are new versions of this XSD that should also be supported. So far, each version added attributes or elements. However, each XSD has a fixed `version` attribute (see example below). I can ignore all other alterations.

How can I best accomodate multiple versions of this XSD into one single class when parsing?

The hacky way I can think of would be to put every version into its own namespace and try to parse each in sequence. I cannot imagine this being the best way, however.

For reference, a sample XSD highlighting the issue:

Version 1.0:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SampleType">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SampleElement" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="1.0" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Version 1.1 (Added `AddedElement`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SampleType">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SampleElement" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="AddedElement" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Version" fixed="1.1" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Version 1.2 (Added attribute `id` to `SampleElement`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="SampleType">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SampleElement">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="AddedElement" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="Version" fixed="1.2" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I think all you  have to do is use latest xsd.  Older version of xml will just have null values for added items in new version of xsd.  The xml will parse.  You just have to add c# code to handle the null items

Comment: I don't think that adding namespaces to make a version unique is an hack. In fact as far as I'm aware that is the way to use versioning in xml schema's. Just make sure that you also use the visual studio namespaces to make your generated code unique. if you keep them in the same vs namespace you will get conflicts.